# Does this patter occur somewhere? Does it have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Consider the following pattern:

```
n = 1 -> (1)
n = 2 -> (2,0), (1,1)
n = 3 -> (3,0), (2,1), (1,1,1)
n = 4 -> (4,0), (3,1), (2,2), (2,1,1), (1,1,1,1)
```

Does this occur somewhere in mathematics (or Computer Science)? Does it have a name?

Comment: I am not sure what your exact pattern is, but there is something similar: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) . Did you mean to maybe have $(2,2)$ in the fourth row?

Comment: You are perfectly right, I corrected it. sorry for the typo

Comment: Mathologer has recently had a very interesting video about counting those partitions: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ8pnCO0nTY

Comment: The link of integer partition was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Write it as formal answer and I will be really happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unordered number theoretic partitions:

$P(n,k)$ is the number of words $x_1\ldots x_k$ of length $k$ over the alphabet $\Bbb N$ such that $x_1\geq x_2\geq \ldots \geq x_k$ and $x_1+\ldots+x_k=n$.

For instance, $n=5$:

$k=1$: $5$

$k=2$: $41,32$

$k=3$: $311,221$

$k=4$: $2111$

$k=5$: $11111$.

There is an iterative formula for $P(n,k)$, but no closed form.